# About News Meta Tag - Good or bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, tags

Does it help seo using "News_Keywords" meta tag for a website that is not including news literally? Or does it hurt ranking on google?

Answer (score 1):

Google dropped support for `news_keywords` year before last. So now, it neither helps nor hurts SEO, no matter whether your website is a news site or not:

> Hi Joost, it looks like we dropped support for this around the time when we removed it from the help center. Keeping it on pages is fine, we just don't use it for Google News anymore. (@JohnMu) February 20, 2018
>
> https://searchengineland.com/google-drops-support-meta-news-keywords-tag-292493

and

> Google News stopped looking for and using the news_keywords meta tag (and in Google News sitemaps) quite some time ago. It doesn't hurt to have them on your site, but it doesn't do any good either,
>
> https://support.google.com/news/publisher-center/thread/1416264?hl=en